# Deploying Python 3 App Heroku: Crashing

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, flask

I finished a project (Week 8 CS50) and wanted to put it on the web.  It works fine in the Cloud9 IDE and the localized web server.  It's "application.py" and uses Flask (configured for me by CS50).

So I read up on deploying, and made several attempts to deploy on Heroku.  Can't get it to work.

Error Log:

- 2017-02-13T04:48:13.132359+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
  crashed to starting
- 2017-02-13T04:48:17.100053+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
  Starting process with command `python application.py`
- 2017-02-13T04:48:20.884225+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
  status 0
- 2017-02-13T04:48:20.902452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
  changed from starting to crashed
- 2017-02-13T04:57:31.197394+00:00
  heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
  path="/" host=goldsteinsentiments.herokuapp.com
  request_id=e917b69b-7636-40c9-9547-a2df2aaa1f3d fwd="50.39.98.15"
  dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
- 2017-02-13T04:57:31.307356+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
  desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
  host=goldsteinsentiments.herokuapp.com
  request_id=096751c7-5cd0-4ba2-8705-6bf61578d516 fwd="50.39.98.15"
  dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Procfile (Copied one from stackoverflow):
"web: python application.py"

Main application.py:
https://github.com/jamesdylangoldstein/sentiments/blob/master/application.py

All the files:
https://github.com/jamesdylangoldstein/sentiments

Comment: Change Procfile content as `web: gunicorn application:app`

Comment: Didn't work.  2017-02-13T06:44:52.938310+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2017-02-13T06:44:52.822690+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2017-02-13T06:44:52.966869+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

Comment: Add `gunicorn` to your requirements.txt file

Comment: Ok, that works!  Now to figure out how to store the API_KEY (I was just typing it in the console)

Answer (score 2):

Steps to deploy:

1) Procfile contains: 
`web: gunicorn application:app`

2) In requirements.txt type:
    `gunicorn`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code you posted on GitHub, there are a few changes I would suggest to overcome this error:

1. Add the following to the end of your python program:

   ```
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       app.run()
   ```

   make sure that app is defined (it seems to be in your case), and that you do not specify a **port** parameter in the .run() method. Heroku will crash if you define a port number in advance.
2. Make sure all dependencies are specified in **requirements.txt**. Make sure that your Procfile and requirements are properly stated as @James Goldstein defined.
3. Some web servers such as Azure require the python app to be named **app.py** by default. I do not know if this is the case with Heroku, but for some servers this could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your created your application using "create_app" factory so your Procfile shuld contains:

`web: gunicorn -w 4 "my_project:create_app()"`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).